# How to disable left edge scrolling in touchpad with synclient command?

Tags: touchpad, synclient

I have disabled the right edge scrolling in touchpad by running:

```
synclient VertEdgeScroll=0
```

But, this only disables the right edge scrolling, my left edge can still scroll. I have no ideas why. I even execute `synclient HorizEdgeScroll=0` which obviously doesn't help at all.

Can anyone let me know how to disable the LEFT edge scrolling? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution 3 minutes after posting the question.

The following command will disable left edge scroll in my touchpad:

```
synclient CircularScrolling=0
```